# Can a deeplink placed in a website, after completion of action in invoked native app, return a value to a website opened in a browser?

Tags: deep-linking, vs-web-site-project, deeplink, upi

I know in case of native apps, an app A that got invoked via a deeplink in another app B can return a value to the calling app B. But, can an app, invoked from a deeplink, placed in a website that's open in browser, return a value to the website/API where deeplink was present? I want to send that return value to the server. Also can progressive web-apps be useful to get return values?